# Notice: Constant WPCF7_AUTOP already defined in

Tags: php, wordpress

Hosting company made updates on the server, then WordPress started to give error.

> Error code : Notice: Constant WPCF7_AUTOP already defined in
>   /home/geriatry/public_html/wp-content/themes/geriatri/functions.php on
>   line 4

**Functions.php :**

```
<?php

define('GERIATRI_URL',get_template_directory_uri());
define( 'WPCF7_AUTOP', true );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_autop_or_not', '__return_false' );




get_template_part('widgets/wp-bootstrap-navwalker');

get_template_part('inc/Bootstrap');

/** start all classes  */
\Aesthetic\Bootstrap::init();
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that problem, try wrapping the definition function in an if conditional that checks that this constant is not already defined. If you don't this when the wp-config file is executed more than one time, it will try to redefine the WPCF7_AUTOP constant.

```
if( !defined('WPCF7_AUTOP') ){
    define('WPCF7_AUTOP', false );
}
```